# Style the border based on a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a card that when the user click on it, the border color should change. It's working fine in the multi select. However, it doesn't work in single select. I want the border color to change for the active element only if multi select is false. So the user would know they can select only one.

Here's my code:

```
const LibraryPicCard: FC<{
    pixList: any;
    thumbnailUrl: string;
    picName: string;
    multiSelect: boolean;
    onCardClick: (fileUrl: string) => void;
}> = ({
    pixList,
    thumbnailUrl,
    picName,
    multiSelect,
    onCardClick
}) => {

    const theme = useTheme();
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
    const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("");

    return (
        <Card
            sx={{
                maxHeight: 300,
                width: 150,
                border: selected ? `1px solid ${theme.palette.primary.main}` : "none"
            }}
            onClick={()=>{
                onCardClick(thumbnailUrl);
                setActiveItem(thumbnailUrl);
                // setSelected(prevCheck => !prevCheck);

                if (multiSelect) {
                    setSelected(prevCheck => !prevCheck);
                } else {
                    const isSelected = !!pixList.find((element:any) => element._id === activeItem);
                    setSelected(isSelected);
                }
            }}
        >
            <CardMedia
                image={ thumbnailUrl }
                sx={{ height: 150, width: 150 }}
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Typography>{ picName }</Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default LibraryPicCard;
```

Comment: `activeItem` won't have updated by the time `isSelected` is calculated, state changes in React are asynchronous. Why not remove the `selected` state entirely, and include some logic based on your `activeItem` to work out if the current item is selected?